# Finding a basis for the kernel and range of $T$

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $T\colon M_{23} \to M_{33}$ be the linear transformation defined by $T(A)=\begin{pmatrix} 2 & -1 \\ 1 & 2 \\ 3&1 \end{pmatrix}\,A$, for $A\in M_{23}$. Find a basis for the kernel and range of $T$.

I don't know how to exactly approach this question. All I know is that the kernel of $T$ would be the nullspace. I row reduced $\begin{pmatrix} 2 & -1 \\ 1 & 2 \\ 3&1 \end{pmatrix}$ and got $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \\ 0&0 \end{pmatrix}$ but I don't know what to do from here.

Comment: Well, the rank of that matrix defining $\,T\,$ is two, if your reduction of the matrix is correct, so its rank is $\,2\,$. Now apply the rank-nullity theorem.

Comment: @DonAntonio: How would the rank-nullity theorem help? Because we're supposed to find the basis for the kernel. I know the rank is 2, the nullity is 0; so there are 2 columns?

Comment: @Deborah Have you learned in the past how to write equations of lines/planes in parametric form? This may be very useful here....

Comment: @Deborah May be helpful: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/161033/the-rank-of-a-multiplication-map-l-colon-m-2-times-3-to-m-3-times-3/161036#161036

Comment: @Deborah: if you first know the dimension of the kernel then you go on to find its basis...On the other hand, this is not too hard: just take the space of all solutions of the homogeneous system defined by your matrix.

Comment: @Don, have you noticed that the domain is not ${\bf R}^2$?

Comment: @Gerry, yes but it doesn't matter: by checking the rank and nullity of the matrix definining the map is possible to deduce stuff...

Answer (score 2):

Let me give you a hint. If you write down a $2 \times 3$ matrix $A$ and compute $T(A)$ you can find what the range looks like and you can also compute the kernel from this. More explicitly, for an arbitrary $2 \times 3$ matrix

$$
A = \begin{bmatrix}
a & c & e\\
b & d & f\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

you will get

\begin{align*}
T(A) = 
\begin{bmatrix}
2 &-1\\
1 & 2\\
3 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
a & c & e\\
b & d & f\\
\end{bmatrix}
= 
\begin{bmatrix}
2a - b & 2c - d & 2e - f\\
a + 2b & c + 2d & e + 2f\\
3a + b & 3c + d & 3e + f\\
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}

Now, this tells you how a matrix in the range of $T$ looks like.

Can you find a basis for the range using this?

Also, for such a matrix $A$ to be in the kernel, you must have $T(A) = (0)_{3 \times 3}$. Then you can find conditions for $a, b, c, d, e, f$ so that you get the zero matrix and with that information you can find what a matrix in the kernel looks like and in that way find a basis for the kernel.

Answer (score 1):

Note that for $A$ to be in the kernel, each column of $A$ must be orthogonal to each row of that $3\times2$ matrix. What can you find that's orthogonal to both $(2,-1)$ and $(1,2)$?